# show(getFragmentManager(),String) is giving error

Tags: android, datepicker, dialog, fragment

I am using a datepicker and when i select the date from it, i want to set it in the Editext named **Eprevd** and for doing it I have made a inner Class (Static) named **PickerDialog.java**

But not getting the proper way to do it.
and also getting error in this statement

> ```
>     pickerDialog.show(getFragmentManager(), "DatePicker");
> ```
>
> Error is -- cannot resolve method show(android.app.fragmentmanager ,java.lang.string)
>
> here Is the code of UpdateActivity.java

```
public class UpdateActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

int year_x, month_x, day_x;
private static EditText Eprevd;

protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_update);
    Eprevd = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.Eupdateprevd);  
}
   public void setDateP(View view)
{
    PickerDialog pickerDialog = new PickerDialog();

   //but this line below is giving error..
    pickerDialog.show(getFragmentManager(), "DatePicker"); // this line
}

                       /////////////////////////////////////////

public static class PickerDialog extends DialogFragment
        implements DatePickerDialog.OnDateSetListener
{
    int year_x, month_x, day_x;
    @Override
            public Dialog onCreateDialog(Bundle savedInstanceState)
        {
            Calendar cal = Calendar.getInstance();
            year_x=cal.get(Calendar.YEAR);
            month_x=cal.get(Calendar.MONTH);
            day_x=cal.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH);
            DatePickerDialog dialog;
            dialog = new DatePickerDialog(getActivity(),this,year_x,month_x,day_x);
            return dialog;
        }

        public void onDateSet(DatePicker view, int year, int month, int dayOfMonth)
        {
            year_x = year;
            month_x = month + 1;
            day_x = dayOfMonth;
            Eprevd.setText(day_x + " / " + month_x + " / " + year_x);
        }
      }
}
```

**Now, what should i do to counter that error..?
Thanks in advance..!**

Comment: What is the error you are getting?

Comment: Error is -- cannot resolve method show(android.app.fragmentmanager ,java.lang.string)

Comment: Ok please use: show(getSupportFragmentManager(), "");

Answer (score 2):

I assume setDateP is being called by a button and set on the xml layout file.  Your using AppCompatActivity, so you should be using getSupportFragmentManager() instead. You can stop give it the "DatePicker" tag to go along with the call.

Comment: now, i have 2 Edit Text in that activity.. and i want to set 2 different dates on them, so  how can i use the same datepicker for both edit texts..?

Comment: @AadeshMishra please accept the answer then add another question for this

Comment: i have accepted it..but due to less reputations it is visible to you..

Comment: can anyone suggest the sample code for using same datepicker for 2 edit texts